# How to use Python to insert keyframes into Rigify's IK-FK switching slider

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python to automatically insert a keyframe IK-FK transition slider,
but it's not working, I've been trying for days and can't get it to work.

[image]

```
bpy.context.object.pose.bones["upper_arm_parent.L"]["IK_FK"] .keyframe_insert(data_path='value', frame=10)
```

Does not have a data_path option for the slider.
I can't find the data_path of the IK-FK slider.

Comment: `bpy.context.object.pose.bones["upper_arm_parent.L"].keyframe_insert(data_path='["IK_FK"]')` ?

Comment: woo~~~~~~~~~ it worked. thank you so much.